# Angular 5 - Proper way to use buttons for state indication in different components

Tags: html, angular, button, radio-button

In my app I have two Angular components let's call them A and B. B is used to display some content and A contains a few buttons which filter B's content. There are also some buttons in B used for further filtering. I want to use the buttons as an indicator of selection, e.g when B displays cats the "cats" button in A should be active.
I managed to get this to work but component A always focuses the first button after refresh etc.

The buttons are implemented like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <button type="button" class="dash-button btn btn-primary" (click)="foo(cats)" id="c"
                appFocusButton="'c' === selectedId" [class.dash-button]="'c' === selectedId">
          Cats
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <button type="button" class="dash-button btn btn-primary" (click)="foo(dogs)" id="d"
                appFocusButton="'d' === selectedId" [class.dash-button]="'d' === selectedId">
          Dogs
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="foo(fish)" id="f"
                appFocusButton="'f' === selectedId" [class.dash-button]="'f' === selectedId">
         Fish
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="foo(birds)" id="b"
                appButtonPrimary [class.dash-button]="'b' === selectedId">
          Birds
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I defined this custom directive to do the focusing:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appFocusButton]'
})
export class FocusButtonDirective {
  constructor(public renderer: Renderer, public elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  @Input()
  set myFocus(value: boolean) {
    if (value) {
      this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
        this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
    }
  }
}
```

And the CSS:

```
.btn-primary {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: x-small;
  white-space:normal;
  background-color: $button-primary;
}
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active {
  background-color: $button-primary-active;
}
.btn-primary:disabled {
  background-color: $button-primary-disabled;
}
.right {
  float:right; display:inline; width: 10%;
}
.col-sm-6 {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.panel-body {
  padding-right: 50px;
}
.panel-heading {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.panel.panel-primary {
  border: none;
}
.icon {
  padding-top: 3px;
  float: right;
}

.input {
  display: none;
}

.dash-button {
  background-color: $button-primary-active;
}
```

I guess the question I am trying to ask here is this, how to stop this first button form getting focused every time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out eventually... There was a inconsistency between an an enum I used and the ids. Something like this:

```
export enum Options {
  c = 'cat',
  d = 'dog',
  b = 'brd',
  f = 'fish'
}

export enum Options {
  c = 'cat',
  d = 'dog',
  b = 'bird',
  f = 'fish'
}
```